# VK SDK for android problems

Tags: java, android, sdk, vk, vk-sdk

I'm using Android Studio. I've downloaded VK SDK from github and added it in my project file.Also I import it

```
import com.perm.kate.api.Api;
```

I authorize, then get my friends with it

```
Api api = new Api(Account.access_token, Constants.API_ID);
users = api.getFriends(Account.user_id, "photo", null, null, null);
```

Insert them in DB

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
       for(int i =0; i< users.size();++i){
                editor.putString("FriendFirstName" + String.valueOf(i), users.get(i).first_name);
                editor.putString("FriendLastName"+ String.valueOf(i), users.get(i).last_name);
                editor.putString("FriendPhoto"+ String.valueOf(i), users.get(i).photo);
           }
    editor.commit();
```

After, I can get any of my friend's name and it's working fine:

```
 Names.add(prefs.getString("FriendFirstName" + String.valueOf(i), null)
        +" "+prefs.getString("FriendLastName" + String.valueOf(i), null) );
```

**BUT** whenever I try get the *photo* or *photo_medium_rec* or any kind of photo it gives me **null**

```
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(),String.valueOf(prefs.getString("FriendPhoto0", null))
                ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//NULL
```

Why is it giving null?

**Addition**

I'm new in programming, so here are some of my dumb questions about VK SDK. What should I use **Api** or **Request** methods like this:

```
VKRequest request = VKApi.uploadWallPhotoRequest(new VKUploadImage(photo, VKImageParameters.jpgImage(0.9f)), 0, 0);
```

Is there any difference between them? How to use *Request*? And how get my personal user information? I couldn't fined any methods in Api to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use official VK SDK [(link)](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk).
And maybe it will be helpfull [(link)](http://interosite.ru/articles/rabota-s-api-vkontakte-v-android)